# linux + run some script without "./" + alias

Tags: linux

I have a Linux machine and I have a script called `load_info` and the script is located in /var

I would like to be able to run the `load_info` script from another directory without having to  prefix the command with "./"

For example if I was in /root I want to be able to type `load_info` (without ./) and have this execute the `/var/load_info` script.

So how do I make it so that if I `cd /root`, I can type `load_info`  and have it run the /var/load_info script.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your shell will search the paths listed in the `$PATH` environment variable for the typed command if it's not fully qualified (e. g. `vi` instead of `/usr/bin/vi`). You can easily add another path to your `$PATH` variable by appending a line in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/your/scripts"
```

As kind of best practice you should also save your script under `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/sbin`, see [hier(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/hier.7.html).

Comment: worked as charm

Answer (score 6):

You need to have the location of the script in an environment variable called *PATH*.

Environment variables are like normal variables you would use in your shell, except that they are persistent throughout your logged in session. Furthermore, if you set them to be loaded into your environment whenever you log in, they will always be set and available all the time.

The *PATH* variable helps the shell find the commands you enter. Its value is a list of directories that the shell searches every time you enter a command. The directory names are separated by colons.

If you are using the *bash* shell (the most common shell used in Linux), then you can see what directories are in the *PATH* variable by typing `echo $PATH` at the command prompt.

Let's just say that the `load_info` script is in  a directory called `/var`. You can add this additional directory to the *PATH* variable by typing:

```
PATH=$PATH:"/var"
```

To make this a permanent change to the *PATH* variable, you can add this to three different files depending on what effect you want.

- If you add it to the `/etc/profile` file, you will make the directory available to all users who log into your system.
- You can add the PATH modification to your own `.bash_profile` file in your home directory, and this will only apply to you when you log in.
- You could also add the PATH modification to the `.bashrc` file file in your home directory, which would have a similar effect to adding it to `.bash_profile`, except that the `.bashrc` file is loaded every time you launch a new shell.

It is also worth mentioning that `/var` is probably not the best place for a script anyway. `/usr/local/bin` would be better. Check out the *heir(7)* man page with `man 7 heir` for more information on what files should go where.

Comment: -1: adding /var is not the solution - the script shouldn't be there.

Comment: Fixed. You can +1 now.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to do this: (running as root)

1. Make a symlink to the `/usr/bin`

   ```
   # ln -s /var/load_info /usr/bin/load_info
   ```
2. Add it to the global `PATH` environment variable:

   ```
   # echo "export PATH=$PATH:/var" >> /etc/profile
   ```

Comment: The PATH variable should never point to individual binaries (or scripts), only to the directories they're contained within.

Comment: If you make a symbolic link to the /usr/bin directory, that will most likely be in the PATH anyway. Even if it isn't you should add /usr/bin to the PATH, not /var.

Comment: I mean they are separate ways.

Answer (score 0):

In OS X (built on Unix) you could do it this way:

1. pico .profile
2. Add this line:
   -alias scriptname="~/Path-to-script/./scriptname"
   -Exit pico and save.
3. . .profile

As seen here:
http://rmcaps.tumblr.com/post/11635645690/help-whats-my-ip-updated